# How to create custom html helper with callback javascript function?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, callback, html-helper

I know that exists **Ajax.ActionLink** function, which signature like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "click me", 
    "SomeAction",
    "SomeController",
    new AjaxOptions { 
        HttpMethod = "POST", 
        OnSuccess = "success" 
    }
)
```

And i can to attach my callback for example:

```
function success(data) {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
    alert(json.someProperty);
}
```

I know that html helpers is extension methods. Question: How to create custom html helper like Ajax.ActionLink in which i can specify callback function. Who can give me example how to make that extension method with ability to take callback function as parameter and execute it.

Comment: what's wrong with the above? looks pretty clear

Comment: What do you want your custom extension method to do?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov - html helper should be custom stylish dropdown checked list, i want to execute callback javascript method when user to check a checkbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Who can give me example how to make that extension method with ability
>   to take callback function as parameter and execute it.

Here:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString ExecuteCallback(this HtmlHelper helper, string callback)
    {
        var script = new TagBuilder("script");
        script.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
        script.InnerHtml = string.Format("{0}();", callback);
        return new HtmlString(script.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));
    }
}
```

and then in your view you could call the helper:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function someCallback() {
        alert('the callback is executed');
    }
</script>
@Html.ExecuteCallback("someCallback")
```